# How to save space in qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

Suppose, I have a qtree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thick,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,},
    edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
        -- +(0,-8pt)
        -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm}
}
\Tree
[.{1}
    [.1-1 ]
    [.1-2 ]
    [.1-3
        [.1-3-1 ]
        [.1-3-2 ]
        [.1-3-3 ]
        [.1-3-4 ]
    ]
    [.1-4 ]
    [.1-5 ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Is it possible to shift nodes 1-2 and 1-4 closer to 1-3?

   [image]
2. Is it possible to make 1-3 subtree grow vertically, so I could get something like this:

   [image]

I know, that `qtrees` can grow both vertically and horizontally. But how to create a hybrid tree?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a plain `TikZ` solution?

Comment: Any solution. I think, the library isn't flexible enough yet.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain `TikZ` and its `trees` library, here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down,node distance=0.5cm,sibling distance=1cm]
\node {1}
child {node {1-1}}
child {node {1-2}}
child {node (13) {1-3}}
child {node {1-4}}
child {node {1-5}}
;
\node [below = of 13, xshift=30pt] (131) {1-3-1};
\node [below = of 131] (132) {1-3-2};
\node [below = of 132] (133) {1-3-3};
\node [below = of 133] (134) {1-3-4};
\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
  \draw (13.south) |- (13\value.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]